# Description of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

Let $x=(x_1, x_2,\dots ,x_d)$, prove that $span_R\{(x\cdot w)^k | w\in S^{d-1}\}$ is the set of all real homogeneous polynomials of degree k with d variables $x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_d$. ($S^{d-1}$ is the unit sphere in $R^d$) Here for any $w=(w_1, w_2, \dots , w_d)\in S^{d-1}$, $x\cdot w=x_1w_1+x_2w_2+\cdots x_dw_d$.

Comment: What does $span_R\{(x\cdot w)^k: w\in S^{d-1}\}$ mean?

Comment: @draks... see my new description of the problem.

Comment: and what is $S^{d-1}$?

Comment: @draks... $S^{d-1}$ is the unit sphere in $R^d$.